# How to save dynamic checkbox and text value from bootstrap datatable in Mysql using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, dynamic, save

I want to save in Mysql db values generated dynamically from db and displayed in bootstrap 3.x dataTable with checkboxes, I know it's possible but how to do it?
 Some times it saves only the current page.
 My codes: 
**Html**:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".submit2").click(function () {

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save this?"))
            {
                var mois = $("#mois").val();
                var mwaka = $("#annee").val();
                var type_staff = $("#type_staff").val();
                var type_dedu = $("#type_dedu").val();
                var type_liste = $("#type_liste").val();
                var oTable = $('#dynamic-table').dataTable();
              
                var rowcollection = oTable.$(".call-check:checked", {"page": "all"});
                rowcollection.each(function (elem) {
                    var checkbox_value = $(elem).val();
                    
//                    var staff = $(this).val();
                    var montat = 'qte' + checkbox_value;
                    if (montat !== '') {
                        var dataString = 'montat=' + montat + '&mois=' + mois + '&mwaka=' + mwaka + '&type_staff='
                                + type_staff + '&type_dedu=' + type_dedu + '&type_liste=' + type_liste + '&staff=' + checkbox_value;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "save_deduction_personalise.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data == 'success') {
                                }
                            }});
                        return false;
                    }

                });  
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }); //EOF
    });
</script>
```

```html
$query_ = $db->prepare("SELECT id,employee_id,first_name,last_name FROM tbl_employees "
            . "WHERE staff_type='" . $type_staff . "'");
    $query_->execute(array());
    $row_count = $query_->rowCount();
    if ($row_count > 0)
        {
        try {
            ?>
            <table class="display table table-bordered" id="dynamic-table" >
                <thead>
                    <tr> 
                        <th>Staff id</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Montant</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    while ($rows = $query_->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $id = $rows['id'];
                        $employee_id = $rows['employee_id'];
                        $names = $rows['first_name'].' '.$rows['last_name'];
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $employee_id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $names; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="item_array[]" type="checkbox" class="call-check" readonly="true"  value="<?php echo $employee_id; ?>" />&nbsp;
                                <input type="number" id="qte" name="qte<?php echo $employee_id; ?>" class="" style="width:230px;" >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    echo $ex->getMessage();
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
        }
?>
<div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="type_liste" id="type_liste">
                                        <option value="1">Tous les staffs</option>
                                        <option value="2">Pérsonalisé</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="annee" id="annee">
                                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                        <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                        <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                        <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                        <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
<input type="submit" class="submit2" name="submit2" value="Enregistrez"/>
```

And my save_deduction_personalise.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
include '../usine/connection.php';

if (!empty($_POST['montat']))
    {
    $mois = $_POST['mois'];
    $mwaka = $_POST['mwaka'];
    $type_staff = $_POST['type_staff']; // permanent or part-time...
    $type_dedu = $_POST['type_dedu'];
    $montat = $_POST['montat'];
    $staff_id = $_POST['staff'];

    $date_ = date('Y-m-d');

    $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];

    $stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM perso_type_deduction WHERE id=?");
    $stmt1->execute(array($type_dedu));
    $rowcount = $stmt1->rowCount();
    if ($rowcount > 0)// ...
        {
        $rows = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $deduction = $rows['title'];
        }

    try {
        $db->beginTransaction();
        

                $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO perso_dedu(employee_id,dedu_id,deduction,montat,umwaka,ukwezi,date_,user_id)"
                        . "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $insert->execute(array($staff_id, $type_dedu, $deduction, $montat, $mwaka, $mois, $date_, $user_name));

            $db->commit();
                $err = 'success';
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $db->rollBack();
        $err = 'error';
    }
    if ($err == 'success')
        {
        echo 'success';
        }
    else
        {
        echo  'error';
        }
    }
?>
```

How can I save all data from text and the checked checkbox values

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean current page? Can you narrow down the problem? Is the correct data being posted to PHP at least?

Comment: Yes data are posted but if the datatable has 3 pages and i check 2 checkbox on 1st page, 2 on 2nd and 1 on 3rd and i click save is the current page which is saved, it's mean that if i'm on 3rd page I save only the one checkbox on it.